# Roll only weekend dates on google sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to create an attendance sheet for my dance class students, which happens on weekends only.

Is there a good way to roll only weekend dates on a google sheet?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put starting date in `A1`, number of days in `A2` and this formula in `A4`:

`=FILTER(ARRAYFORMULA(A1+ row(INDIRECT("A1:A"&A2))),
WEEKDAY(ARRAYFORMULA(A1+ row(INDIRECT("A1:A"&A2))),2)>5)`

The result:

[image]